# Are there general or specific iOS6 performance issues on iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, performance, ios

I would like to upgrade my iPhone 4 to iOS6 but I'm wondering if I will get performance loss (as when I upgraded my iPhone 3G to iOS4 : terrible).
Can someone confirm that it won't affect my day to day use?

Comment: It hasn’t affected me on my iPod touch 4G, which is more underpowered than the iPhone 4.

Comment: I just wanted to say that the only time I've seen a performance hit on iOS 5 and iOS 6 is when an app needs space for working files on the device's storage and you are low. This sometimes starts with as much as 1 GB free on the device, so this question is more about whether you run with greater than 1 GB of free space or are packing your device to nearly full.

Comment: I installed iOS6 yesterday and it all run fine! I'm just a little bit disapointed not having access to some new feature due to "marketware" incompatibility...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been running iOS 6 since Friday night (I ran the Golden Master that became release) on my iPhone 4.

Safari feels snappier (and show improvement on SunSpider benchmarks).

I have not noticed any degradation like the 3G iOS 4 craziness that apple gave us (I went through that as well).

I am very happy and using it (everyday) and it feels a bit better in most things than 5.

Comment: Just to add - camera is so much faster too now.

Answer (score 5):

I'm running iOS 6 on iPhone 4 and the first thing I noticed is a clear performance boost. Everything feels smoother and snappier. Animations are more fluid too.

Comment: That is a good news!

Answer (score 1):

I have iPhone 4 and yesterday i upgraded it to iOS 6. But really - i can't find performance change. New maps, new apps...but that's all. For me there is no performance change, or it just too small and i can't feel it now
So don't be affraid of the upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I have an iPhone 4 running iOS 6 and haven't noticed any performance or battery life issues. In fact, the phone is 18 months old (so the battery isn't new), and before charging it earlier today, it was at 14% battery with 2 days 20 hours of standby, 5 hours 30 minutes of usage. I'd say that's pretty good!