# Can the iPad / iPad 2 handle iOS 6?

Tags: ipad, performance, ios

I've heard anecdotal evidence of iOS 6 seriously impairing the performance of the iPhone 4 (and had a poor personal experience with it on iOS 5). I was wondering if anyone has had any problems upgrading older iPads to iOS 6.

We've got an original iPad and an iPad 2 and aside from not wanting to lose Google maps I'm worried that the update will negatively affect our devices.

Is this worry backed up by reviews or experience of those who have upgraded already?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short version:

- Original iPad, no.
- iPad 2, yes.

The details also matter for some features, per http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/#compatible:

[image: iOS 6 Supported Devices]

There's also the device specific features fine print:

1. Turn-by-turn navigation is available only on iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, and iPad 2 or later with cellular data capability. Flyover is available only on iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, iPad 2 or later, and iPod touch (5th generation).
2. Siri is available on iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, iPad (3rd generation), and iPod touch (5th generation) and requires Internet access.
3. FaceTime video calling requires a FaceTime-enabled device for the caller and recipient and a Wi-Fi connection. FaceTime over a cellular network requires iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, or iPad (3rd generation) with cellular data capability.
4. Offline Reading List is available on iPhone 4 or later and iPad 2 or later.
5. Made for iPhone hearing aids require iPhone 4S or iPhone 5.
6. Panorama is available on iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, and iPod touch (5th generation).

Comment: Much as I put faith in what Apple officially say, I have a friend who says her iPhone 4 has slowed down since the udate, and I have personally experienced slow down when upgrading a 3GS to iOS 5 in the past.

Comment: I said nothing about the speed of the device. Not to mention that speed is immensely subjective, given how much it can vary, situationally.

Comment: My 3GS was rendered almost unusable by update to iOS5 I rely on my iPad 2 and want to make sure that it's not going to go down the same path. If it's got the same processor as the iPhone4S then I think it should be okay.

Comment: I would add that I have see no confirmed case where iOS 6 is seriously slow on any device that officially supports that release. The press, bloggers and here - no one has shown a reproducible case of a specific or general slowdown for any iPod, iPhone or iPad. Other than the iPad not running this release by design, this seems a safe upgrade if you are OK with Maps coverage in your area.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using iOS 6 on an iPad 2 successfully for several days. I would say that it hasn't impacted the performance at all. In fact, in a few areas (notably Safari) it is noticeably faster.

Comment: This seems to be the consensus - iPod's are faster or the same on iOS 6, iPhones, and iPads. I don't know if they tuned things better, understood and killed features that would be marginal (offline reading, flyover, turn by turn, etc...) but the end result is no regressions in speed with iOS 6.

Answer (score 4):

There is no performance issues using iOS 6 on an iPhone 4 as per this post [on the topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64589/ios6-performance-issue-on-iphone-4/64591#64591).

You can upgrade the iPad 2 (which has an A5 chip as opposed to the A4 on the iPhone 4) to iOS 6 but the original iPad is not supported. Details of supported devices and full functionality available [on Apple's website](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/).